# If condition wrongly working

Tags: php, if-statement

The Following PHP if condition statement is processing wrong and is not working.
File $fname has text values: "990,1000" with a comma in between:

```
$myfile = fopen($fname, "r") or die("<script 
type='text/javascript'>window.location.href = 
'http://www.autorekrooter.com/activation.html';</script>");
$dt=fread($myfile,filesize($fname));
//File fname has values: "990, 1000"
fclose($myfile);
$myArray = explode(',', $dt);
//Now checking if Limit expired or not?  
echo "<br>myArray[0] values is: " . $myArray[0] . " myArray[1] value is: " . 
$myArray[1];
if ($myArray[0]>=$myArray[1]){
echo "<script>alert('You can't proceed further');</script>";    
//echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href = 'register.html';</script>";
exit();
}
else{
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href = 
'gui.php';</script>";
echo "You can proceed";
exit();
}
```

When I run the above in a php file the if statement always takes value of `myArray[0] >= myArray[1]` as true and show the **reigster.html** whereas in the `$fname` file it is `990,1000 myArray[0]=990` and `myArray[1]=1000` so `myArray[0]` should not be greater than `myArray[1]` and the else statement should run but the opposite is happening.

Any suggestions as to why this is not working?
Many Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Can you show us the content of $dt

Comment: $dt="990,1000" it reads from the file. Given in the comments @Grumpy

Comment: Convert $myArray[0] and $myArray[1] to int then check like $firstval= (int) $myArray[0]; $secondval= (int) $myArray[1] and compare $firstval and $secondval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:
`f ((int)$myArray[0]>=(int)$myArray[1]){`

Comment: Yes your code of typecasting worked for me. I will accept this as an answer please upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a newline (`\n` or `\r\n`) at the end of your file (`$myfile`). So `myArray[1]` actually looks like `"1000\n"`.

`var_dump("990" >= "1000\n");` returns `bool(true)`.

You're comparing strings that PHP can't convert to numbers so you get an unexpected result.

Comment: Output from the PHP script: Value in DT variable: 990,1000

Comment: How do I remove \r\n at end of line? any suggestions.. @timclutton

Comment: just add , after the second value, so content becomes 990,1000,

Comment: @PuneetMathur You're going to need to debug this a bit more thoroughly than just using `echo`. At least use `var_dump($myArray);` to inspect the values.  _Remember that viewing the result in a web browser will remove whitespace!_

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
$myArray = array_map('intval', explode(',', $dt));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **intval** to get the integer value only.
Try this

```
if (intval($myArray[0])>=intval($myArray[1])){
     echo "<script>alert('You can't proceed further');</script>";    
//echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href = 'register.html';</script>";
exit();
}
else{
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href = 
'gui.php';</script>";
echo "You can proceed";
exit();
}
```

I thing it will work for you.